# Why is ndarray printing inconsistent?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I wasn't having this problem earlier, but for some reason it starting happening, and I have no idea why? the rest of the program doesn't work as intended, and I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

The most relevant code is below:

```
x_train = np.array(x_input_sequences_train)
y_train = np.array(y_output_words_train)
x_test = np.array(x_input_sequences_test)
y_test = np.array(y_output_words_test)
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
print('x train')
print(x_train)
print('y train')
print(y_train)
# print(findArrayToWords(y_train))
print('x test')
print(x_test)
print('y test')
print(y_test)
```

now the rest of the arrays print a truncated value, as is expected, but for some very weird reason, `y_train` prints the full list? Even though the type is the same and it should be printing like the rest?

Here's the output:

```
(938, 24)
(938, 1)
(3753, 24)
(3753, 1)
x train
[[2.12404418e-04 4.24808836e-04 6.37213254e-04 ... 3.82327952e-03
  4.03568394e-03 4.24808836e-03]
 [1.48683093e-03 4.46049278e-03 1.91163976e-03 ... 3.39847069e-03
  1.91163976e-03 4.24808836e-04]
 [8.49617672e-03 8.70858114e-03 8.92098556e-03 ... 1.08326253e-02
  1.10450297e-02 1.12574342e-02]
 ...
 [9.17587086e-02 1.01954121e-02 4.49447749e-01 ... 4.44774851e-01
  1.23194562e-02 2.27272727e-02]
 [1.27442651e-03 1.48683093e-03 2.57009346e-02 ... 1.91163976e-03
  7.66779949e-02 4.24808836e-04]
 [1.78419711e-02 3.27102804e-02 1.27442651e-02 ... 1.27442651e-02
  2.63381478e-02 8.15632965e-02]]
y train
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[6.000e-04 3.900e-03 2.600e-03 9.000e-04 6.600e-03 2.600e-03 9.300e-03
 3.000e-03 5.500e-03 1.400e-03 1.290e-02 1.390e-02 5.400e-03 1.510e-02
 7.500e-03 9.000e-04 2.600e-03 3.400e-03 6.000e-04 6.000e-03 7.000e-04
 6.000e-04 1.340e-02 2.180e-02 5.300e-03 2.600e-03 5.200e-03 9.000e-04
 7.000e-04 2.480e-02 2.560e-02 7.500e-03 5.500e-03 1.340e-02 7.000e-04
 9.000e-04 5.100e-03 2.890e-02 3.030e-02 9.000e-04 2.410e-02 1.600e-03
 9.800e-03 3.060e-02 8.000e-04 9.000e-04 1.600e-03 8.200e-03 1.400e-02
 3.600e-03 1.610e-02 8.400e-03 3.610e-02 1.520e-02 7.000e-04 0.000e+00
 1.380e-02 4.800e-03 7.000e-04 6.000e-04 1.520e-02 9.800e-03 4.200e-03
 1.620e-02 2.990e-02 2.760e-02 5.700e-03 1.040e-02 3.860e-02 3.840e-02
 2.000e-04 2.350e-02 4.130e-02 4.150e-02 7.000e-04 6.000e-04 3.180e-02
 1.890e-02 1.340e-02 4.270e-02 1.630e-02 2.240e-02 2.020e-02 3.740e-02
 3.390e-02 2.600e-03 6.900e-03 3.450e-02 5.800e-03 8.400e-03 1.210e-02
 6.000e-03 6.000e-03 3.920e-02 5.400e-03 7.400e-03 4.780e-02 2.600e-03
 2.660e-02 4.840e-02 4.860e-02 7.000e-04 3.000e-03 5.300e-03 7.000e-04
 5.040e-02 4.700e-02 7.000e-04 1.630e-02 7.000e-04 1.600e-03 6.000e-03
```

and then it carries on.

The full code file for wider context:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import csv
import numpy as np
from numpy import argmax, isin, ndarray
from pandas.io import api
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, Input, Activation, concatenate, Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

def prepare_data(): 
    GrimmBrothersText = open("GrimmBrothers.txt", "r")
    GBFullArray = re.findall(r"[\w]+|[^\s\w]", GrimmBrothersText.read())

    # firstly, identify the most uncommon words, because input sequences with those should be removed
    wordCountDict = {} # empty dictionary, where words counted will go i.e. 'the': 329, 'cat': 132, etc. 
    wordIntLabel = {} # dict to map words to integers 
    uniqueWordCounter = 0 # this is needed to assign an integer value to every word, so they can then be hot encoded 
    sequence_length = 25 # allow five preceeding words before making a prediction on the next 
    x_input_sequences_full = [] 
    y_output_words_full = [] 
    temp_sequence = []
    for i in range(0, len(GBFullArray) - 1): 
        # iterate through every term in the full text, to record the number of times the word is repeated (to filter low occuring words) 
        word = GBFullArray[i].lower() # words with different capitalisation should be counted as the same 
        if word in list(wordCountDict.keys()):
            wordCountDict[word] += 1 # add 1 to the word count of said word
        else: 
            wordIntLabel[word] = uniqueWordCounter
            uniqueWordCounter += 1
            wordCountDict[word] = 1 # add the word to the dictionary because it's not already there 

    # csv was already written, so no need to repeat code. Uncomment to write a new csv 
    # with open('GrimmWords.csv', 'w') as csv_file:  
    #     writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    #     for key, value in wordCountDict.items():
    #        writer.writerow([key, value])

    fullWordIntegerList = []
    for key, value in wordIntLabel.items():
        fullWordIntegerList.append(value)

    # get the full vocabulary in encoded values as a list (to use for translation from words to encoded values) 
    encodedWordList = to_categorical(fullWordIntegerList)

    def findHotEncodedValue(word): 
        # find the word in the word-to-integer dictionary 
        wordInteger = wordIntLabel[word.lower()]

        # find the hot encoded integer in the array of the full vocabulary
        return encodedWordList[wordInteger]

    def findOriginalWord(wordNum):
        if isinstance(wordNum, int) or isinstance(wordNum, np.float32) or isinstance(wordNum, np.float64):
            key_list = list(wordIntLabel.keys())
            val_list = list(wordIntLabel.values())
            wordNum = wordNum * 10000
            position = val_list.index(round(wordNum))
            return key_list[position]
        # elif isinstance(wordNum, np.ndarray):
        #     # if hot encoded value: 
        #     invertedInteger = argmax(wordNum)
        #     key_list = list(wordIntLabel.keys())
        #     val_list = list(wordIntLabel.values())
        #     position = val_list.index(invertedInteger)
        #     return key_list[position]   
        else: 
            print(f"recieved type {type(wordNum)}; wrong type. Value: {wordNum}")
        

    def findArrayToWords(array):
        newArr = []
        for i in array: 
            print(i, "   ====>   ", findOriginalWord(i))
            newArr.append(findOriginalWord(i))
        return newArr
        # try:
        #     newArr = []
        #     for i in array: 
        #         newArr.append(findOriginalWord(i))
        #     return newArr
        # except:
        #     # It's clearly not iterable, so it must be an int 
        #     return findOriginalWord(array)
            

    # define the list of infrequent words 
    infreq_words = []
    for key, value in wordCountDict.items(): 
        if value <= 4: 
            infreq_words.append(key.lower())
    # if at 4, 3072 infrequent words 
    # if at 3, 2805 infrequent words 
    # if at 2, 2383 infrequent words 
    # if at 1, 1666 infrequent words 
    print(len(infreq_words))
    print(infreq_words)

    # encode the words, add them to their input / output list, and remove those which are infrequent words
    for i in range(0, len(GBFullArray) - 1): 
        # change the word to its hot encoded value first, before adding it to its input sequence list or output list
        word = GBFullArray[i].lower()
        hotEncodedWord = findHotEncodedValue(word)
        wordNum = wordIntLabel[word]
        normalisedWordNum = wordNum / 10000
        invalidDataSample = False

        if word in infreq_words: 
            # the word that was going to be added to an input /output data sample is infrequent, so remove the data sample all together. 
            # set a boolean invalidDataSample flag: 
            invalidDataSample = True

        # create the input sequences and matching output words. 
        if (i % sequence_length != 0):
            temp_sequence.append(normalisedWordNum) # not sure if x_input needs to be hot encoded, but right now they are not, only the y_output
        else: 
            # it's the sequence_length(th) element, so add to the x and y lists, if the data sample is valid 
            if invalidDataSample: 
                temp_sequence = [] # just reset the temp_sequence, and don't add a data sample 
                invalidDataSample = False # reset the boolean flag 
            else: 
                x_input_sequences_full.append(np.array(temp_sequence))
                y_output_words_full.append(np.array(normalisedWordNum)) # [int] but changed to just `int` 
                temp_sequence = [] # reset temporary sequence 

     # pop first element because sequence list is empty 
    x_input_sequences_full.pop(0)
    y_output_words_full.pop(0)

    # confirm everything is A-OKAY   
    # print(wordIntLabel)
    # print(x_input_sequences_full)
    # print(y_output_words_full)
    # print(len(x_input_sequences_full))
    # print(len(y_output_words_full))
    print(x_input_sequences_full[1], y_output_words_full[1])
    print(x_input_sequences_full[2], y_output_words_full[2])
    # print(findArrayToWords(x_input_sequences_full[0]), findArrayToWords(y_output_words_full[0]))

    return x_input_sequences_full, y_output_words_full, wordIntLabel, findHotEncodedValue, findOriginalWord, findArrayToWords, sequence_length


x_input_sequences_full, y_output_words_full, wordIntLabel, findHotEncodedValue, findOriginalWord, findArrayToWords, sequence_length = prepare_data()

# print(findArrayToWords(x_input_sequences_full[0]), findArrayToWords(y_output_words_full[0]))

test_split = 0.2
n = round(test_split * len(x_input_sequences_full))

# TRAINING DATASET
x_input_sequences_train = x_input_sequences_full[:n]
y_output_words_train = y_output_words_full[:n]

# TESTING DATASET
x_input_sequences_test = x_input_sequences_full[n:]
y_output_words_test = y_output_words_full[n:]

x_train = np.array(x_input_sequences_train)
y_train = np.array(y_output_words_train)
x_test = np.array(x_input_sequences_test)
y_test = np.array(y_output_words_test)
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
print('x train')
print(x_train)
print('y train')
print(y_train)
# print(findArrayToWords(y_train))
print('x test')
print(x_test)
print('y test')
print(y_test)

x_train = x_train.reshape(len(x_train), 1, (sequence_length - 1))
x_test = x_test.reshape(len(x_test), 1, (sequence_length - 1))
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_train)

y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1, 1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(-1, 1, 1)
print(y_train.shape)

print(y_test.shape)
print('y test')
print(y_test)
print('y train')
print(type(y_train))
print(np.asarray(y_output_words_train))

# model architecture

# each input is of height one, length 3 
# each input is of height 1, length sequence_length 
# (1, sequence_length) 

model = Sequential()
# model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(96,return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5, input_shape=(1, sequence_length))))
# model.add(Dense(64, activation='linear'))
# model.add(Dense(4709, activation='sigmoid'))
# model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

lstm_input = Input(shape=(1, (sequence_length - 1)), name='lstm_input')
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, name='lstm_1', return_sequences=True, activation='sigmoid'))(lstm_input)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, name='lstm_2', return_sequences=True, activation='sigmoid'))(x)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, name='lstm_3', return_sequences=True, activation='sigmoid'))(x)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, name='lstm_4', return_sequences=True, activation='sigmoid'))(x)
x = Dropout(0.4, name='lstm_dropout_0')(x) # for normalisation
x = Dense(4709, name='dense_0', activation='sigmoid')(x)
# x = Activation('sigmoid', name='sigmoid_0')(x)
output = Activation('sigmoid', name='linear_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs=lstm_input, outputs=output)
adam = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001)
sgd = optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# x_new_raw = [
#     ['and', 'by', 'the', 'side'], # and by the side of
#     ['and', 'in', 'one', 'of'], # and in one of
#     ['and', 'about', 'the', 'time'],
#     ['I','must','have','the']
# ]
# x_new = []
# for i in x_new_raw:
#     temp = []
#     for j in i: 
#         temp.append(wordIntLabel[j.lower()])
    
#     x_new.append(temp)

# x_new = np.array(x_new)
# x_new = x_new.reshape(-1, 1, 8)

# print(x_new)
# print(x_new.shape)
print(x_train.shape)

print(len(wordIntLabel))
# print(findArrayToWords(x_test[0]))
print(x_test[0])
# print(findArrayToWords(x_test[1]))
# print(findArrayToWords(x_test[2]))

model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=100, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Score:', score)

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

print(y_pred)

# for i in range(0, len(y_pred)):
#     print(x_test[i], y_pred[i)

print(y_pred.shape)
print(findArrayToWords(x_test[0]))
for i in y_pred:
    print(findArrayToWords(i))

model.summary()

print(y_pred[0])
print(findOriginalWord(y_pred[0][0]))

print(findOriginalWord(['and', 'by', 'the', 'side']))




# # evaluation

# y_test_predicted = model.predict(ohlcv_test)
# y_test_predicted = y_normaliser.inverse_transform(y_test_predicted)
# y_predicted = model.predict(ohlcv_histories)
# y_predicted = y_normaliser.inverse_transform(y_predicted)

# assert unscaled_y_test.shape == y_test_predicted.shape
# real_mse = np.mean(np.square(unscaled_y_test - y_test_predicted))
# scaled_mse = real_mse / (np.max(unscaled_y_test) - np.min(unscaled_y_test)) * 100
# print(scaled_mse)

# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plt.gcf().set_size_inches(22, 15, forward=True)

# start = 0
# end = -1

# real = plt.plot(unscaled_y_test[start:end], label='real')
# pred = plt.plot(y_test_predicted[start:end], label='predicted')

# # real = plt.plot(unscaled_y[start:end], label='real')
# # pred = plt.plot(y_predicted[start:end], label='predicted')

# plt.legend(['Real', 'Predicted'])

# plt.show()

# from datetime import datetime
# model.save(f'basic_model.h5')
```

Why is this happening???

Comment: where's the `shape` prints?

Comment: I just copied the lower part of the output, my bad. I'll edit it to include the `shape` prints

Comment: numpy print starts using ellipsis at 1000 elements, `(938, 1)` isn't enough.

Comment: Ohh? fair enough my bad. Thanks so much